# How to parse Date();

Tags: android, date

**Here is my code**

```
    String date = "2020-12-15 12:30:07";

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    Date d = new Date();
    CharSequence crrnt = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", d.getTime());

    Date date1 = null;//start
        try {
           date1 = dateFormat.parse(date);
           System.out.println("date1  === " );
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("date 2 === " );
        }
```

But none have been printed. How to parse it.

Comment: Well something must be getting printed here.  What is it?

Comment: I tried to print it outside the `try catch`, but nothing came out. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: do you mean `System.out.println("date1  === " + date1  );`?

Comment: this is done at the click button @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: i tried it. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Please re-read the above comment by @Zain ... your print statement doesn't actually include the parsed date.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

First solution:

```
string inputDate=........;
try {
Simple DateFormat FORMATTING_PATTERN= new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD");
Parse Position.Position= new ParsePosition(0);
Date stringToDate = FORMATTING_PATTERN.Parse(inputDate, Position);
}

catch { }
```

Second solution:

```
final DateFormat PARSING_PATTERN = new SimpleDateFormat("your code");
final DateFormat FORMATTING_PATTERN= new SimpleDateFormat("your code", Locale.ITALIAN);
String inputDate = .....;
inputDate.replace("CEST", "+00:00");
String outputDate="";
try {
    Date d= PARSING_PATTERN.parse(data);
    outputDate= FORMATTING_PATTERN.format(d).toString();
} 
catch (ParseException e) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for comm and answer. My bad.
It's just like cache. I restarted IDE then it worked.